# Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() should not throw an exception

Tags: magento2, admin

I am trying to obtain the collection of table in magento2 and i stuck with below error

> Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getConnection() on null in D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\slideteam_m2\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Wrapper\UiComponent.php on line 0

Do you have any idea how we can solve it!

Your answers are appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: please add code